# What's the equivalent to SQL LEN in android Room database?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'm trying to query a table where column data length is greater than 5, something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEN(column) > 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LENGTH` scalar function is probably what you're looking for. You can read more about it [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length).